# Multiple Regression - Converting Standardized Coefficients to Unstandardized

Tags: matlab, regression, standardized

I recently performed a multiple regression in MATLAB using a standardized set of data, and I was wondering if it possible to convert the standardized coefficients from the regression into usable unstandardized coefficients. I feel like this might be possible using the calculated mean and standard deviation of each variable used in the regression, but I would appreciate any help before making any mistakes.

Comment: What answer has your own efforts led you to? What don't you understand or are unsure of?

Comment: I found this possible solution but wasn't sure if it was as simple as multplying by the ratio of the standard deviations: https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats1/x92.pdf